Button label which has ← at the left
I want to make the button label such as
<button style="width:80px">←  back  <button>

then I want to put the ← at the left and set back in the middile of button.
such as
 ____________
|←   back    |

I think I should use Flex ,but a little bit confused, because
← should be at the left
back should be in the middle of button itselt not a remaining space
How can I make this?

You can use a grid, or you can give the middle part a right margin as wide as the left arrow element is.

I think you could use another approach with position absolute and align the text at center
With this you will achieve two things

Keeping the arrow always at left
Align the text to the center not considering the arrow at left (as the arrow will have position absolute is not going to align the text at the center)

<button>
  <span class="arrow">←</span>
  <span class="text">back</span>
</button>

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

button .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}


As the backarrow is just a visual clue I would remove it from the DOM and instead show it in a before pseudo element positioned left.
Browsers seem to already center the content of buttons so this snippet doesn't bother to add a text-align for the back text.


button::before {
  content: '←';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

button {
  position: relative;
}
<button style="width:80px">back</button>




I got a little bit carried away, and decided to explore logical properties with this question. As a result, I came up with this (but it doesn't justify a new answer): demo.

Excellent! [but is it called 'forward' in right to left - I suppose it is].

I only had access to one person, today, that was raised in Egypt speaking Arabic (which is a right to left language) and I didn't think to check that the terms were considered "forward" and "backward," but I did ask him which direction "forward" and "backward" would be in his language, and he was kind enough to confirm my assumptions that "forward" in direction would point to the left, and backward would point to the right. That doesn't necessarily apply to any other rtl language though.

You can indeed use Flexbox. The key is to use a combination of justify-content and margin properties to place the arrow to the left and the text in the center.


<button style="width: 80px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; position: relative;">
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 8px;">←</span>
    <span style="margin: 0 auto;">back</span>
</button>




You can remove everything but the width and position declarations and have the same result.

Thank you very much I understood absolute is the key in this way



.button {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
       width: 100px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
       padding: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       background-color: #f0f0f0;
       cursor: pointer;
       position: relative;
    }

.button .arrow {
       position: absolute;
       left: 5px; /* Adjust the left position as needed */
     }

.button .text {
       flex-grow: 1;
       text-align: center;
 }
    <button class="button">
       <span class="arrow">←</span>
       <span class="text">back</span>
   </button>




You can try this:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
<!-- With left arrow aligned to the left and the "Back" in the center of the button -->
<button class="grid-container">
  <span class="grid-item" style="text-align:left;">&larr;</span>
  <span class="grid-item">Back</span>
  <span class="grid-item"></span>
</button>
<br>

<!-- With the "Back" in the center of the button (for comparison) -->
<button class="grid-container">
  <span class="grid-item"></span>
  <span class="grid-item">Back</span>
  <span class="grid-item"></span>
</button>



